# Css Responsive navigation with drop down sub menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

So here is my Codepen version of it
http://codepen.io/pixel8-designs/pen/nkGfa

First I'll start by saying this is a version of someone elses code that I have massively forked,

And what I am trying to do is make a drop down inside of it. 
I was going to try a checkbox hack but since its already in-use i tried using onClick jQuery..

On my codepen I have made the Div Submenu under all of it because if you click it full screen i dont like how it looks, I want it to drop under them all...

If any one would be able to take a look and see an easy way to get this to work I would greatly appreciate it!

I would have uploaded the code here also but since that it was an effort to figure out how to paste it all in with the atrl+k... its all on codepen, works in Chrome if not firefox..

Thanks again

Comment: Could you copy it to JSFiddle instead? For some reason its not restoring it to your given code when deleting something.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap) Its easy to do any kind of stuff you are in need of. You can also customise it to suit your needs also you you can easily adopt your dropdown menu with this. Jumpstart into his framework and your work gets easier :)

Cheers !